# D3.js - update a single element

Tags: d3.js

This great [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) shows how to update all svg elements. How would I select just one element and update it? I know how to add event listeners in D3.js to update single elements, but what if I need to update an element due to some external factor? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page covers all of the ways you can select element(s): https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections

For example, you could do something like:

```
var circle = svg.select("#circle-0");
circle
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .style("fill", "steelblue");
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/elevine/FYY9k/

Comment: Well that is part of the solution, and I am able to select elements. I am looking for a simple example in the context of the tutorial I linked. I am actually working with a more complex force diagram though. When I make a selection and change an attribute on a node of my force diagram, I lose the position and all links to/from the node.

Comment: I've added an example of selecting a single element and updating it, based off of the tutorial.  If you could post some sample code and/or a jsfiddle, it would help in trying to solve the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks. You answered the question I had asked, but I can't get that to work in the context of my updating force diagram. I made a better example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BNFe/) if you'd like to have a look? The button click function at the bottom is where I'd like to modify a node.

Comment: Ok. New [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BNFe/1/) and it is working (using a css class selector). I'm not sure what I was doing wrong previously. Thanks so much.